# Timestamp difference in MYSQL between DOWN and UP event but not between UP and DOWN event

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have MYSQL database and i'd like to write a query that will return me the timedifference in seconds betwen DOWN and UP event. I need difference ONLY between DOWN and UP event, but NOT the difference betwen UP and DOWN event.

Here is a sample of my database records:

```
comment       date_time       type
  146   2015-05-20 07:07:34    UP
  146   2015-05-20 07:02:32   DOWN
  146   2015-05-20 00:03:13    UP
  146   2015-05-19 23:57:36   DOWN
```

so because i need a difference only between DOWN and UP event, the difference between `2015-05-20 00:00:00` and `2015-05-20 12:00:00` should be `00:05:02`

I have a MYSQL query:

```
SELECT UP1.comment, sum(timestampdiff(second, DOWN1.date_time, UP1.date_time)) AS down_time_d FROM
(SELECT comment, date_time, type FROM event
    WHERE  comment like '%146%'
    AND event.date_time BETWEEN '2015-05-20 00:00.00' and '2015-05-20 13:23:58'
    AND type = 'SENSOR_UP'
) AS UP1,

(SELECT comment, date_time, type FROM event
    WHERE  comment like '%146%'
    AND event.date_time BETWEEN '2015-05-20 00:00.00' and '2015-05-20 13:23:58'
    AND type = 'SENSOR_DOWN'
) AS DOWN1
WHERE UP1.comment=DOWN1.comment
GROUP BY comment
```

The issue of this query is that returns me the difference between DOWN an UP and between UP and DOWN. Returns, that my difference is `06:54:17` instead of my expectation `00:05:02`. If there is more DOWN and UP records, it makes a difference between all posible combinations between DOWN and UP.

What should i change in my query that wil return me only the SUM of timedifferences between DOWN and UP event?

Thanx for help

Comment: Can't you modify the table structure to have `senser_up date_time, sensor_down date_time` columns? so that each of the events have both `up` and `down` times in the same record!!

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, but instead was thinking of adding a fourth column, up_down_event_id, that would link the two up down records.The point is, that there is surely room to simplify this.

Comment: of course, however event id should be provisioned

Comment: How regimented is this data feed?  Could the event sequence be, for example, `UP, UP, DOWN, DOWN, UP`?  How should these be catered for?

Comment: That solutions would be great and would simplify thing a lot, but database structeru is like it is, and it's not possible to change anything. So i need to find a soluttion with that kind of data. Looking for ID is not possible, cause there is more comment types (146, 145, 144, 143, ...) and all of them have DOWN and UP events. So ID 1000 is for commetn 146, ID 1001 for 145, ID 1002 for 146...there is no key to connect ID with comment or date_time. ID is just random number for event, no matter to which comment type this event belongs.

It must be some way to solve this with data like those are?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to paraphrase what you are asking for...
- The total time a system is down

A system is down from the moment of a `DOWN` event until any subsequent event.

If that subsequent event is also a `DOWN`, it simply continues to stay down.

If there is no subsequent event, the system stays down until "now".

```
SELECT
    comment,
    SUM(down_time)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        down_event.comment,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(
            second,
            down_event.date_time,
            COALESCE(
                MIN(next_event.date_time),
                '2015-05-20 13:23:58'
            )
        )       AS down_time
    FROM
        event   down_event
    LEFT JOIN
        event   next_event
            ON  next_event.comment      =    down_event.comment
            AND next_event.date_time    >    down_event.date_time
            AND next_event.date_time BETWEEN '2015-05-20 00:00.00'
                                       AND   '2015-05-20 13:23:58'
    WHERE
            down_event.type         =    'DOWN'
        AND down_event.date_time BETWEEN '2015-05-20 00:00.00'
                                   AND   '2015-05-20 13:23:58'
    GROUP BY
        down_event.comment,
        down_event.date_time
)
    AS down_time
GROUP BY
    comment
;
```

Comment: First i thank you for the answer. I actualy solved that the system is down between midnight and UP and DOWN and now in PHP. Here i need just timedifference in seconds between event DOWN and UP.